# Can't access state of store vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules

Here is of main file
/main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import router from './router';
import store  from './store/index.js';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  vuetify,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Here is store
/store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';


Vue.use(Vuex);

const store= new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    appNumber: 0
  }
})

export default store
```

Here is template
/template

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{appNumber()}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  computed: {
    }
  ,
  methods: {
    appNumber() {
      return this.$store.state.appNumber;
  }
}};
</script>
```

The error is
" Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state') "

I try to access file store index.js by import directly in template and it work. But I want to declare it on main.js file and can use by all file

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. It should work the way you did it

Answer (score 1):

Normally, we don't access the state directly outside of the store. Normally, we write getters and access them as follows: `this.$store.getters["getAppNumber"]`

In your store, define the getter as:

```
getters: {
   getAppNumber: state => state.appNumber,
}
```

Even better would be if you would `...mapGetters(["getAppNumber"])` to the `computed` property of the consuming component. Because then you can simply access the value with `this.getAppNumber`

Comment: thanks for ur help, I see what u say. But I found my error. This cause by version vuex. I updated the lastest version of vuex. And when I downgrade version and it work

Answer (score 0):

I could see your are trying to access the `$store.state` by using methods.

Beside using `getter` in [Goga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76380208), you are supposed to use `computed` if you want to get a [reactive calculcated](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#computed-caching-vs-methods) value within a instance.

And that you don't need the blanket anymore.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ appNumber }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  computed: {
     appNumber(){
         return this.$store.state.appNumber;
     }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Now I can use many ways to access state